# is it possible to upcast an increment operator from int to long in java?

Tags: java, casting

let's say I assign max value for an int variable.

`int a = 2147483647;`

if I increment, it causes an overflow.

`System.out.println(++(long)a);`

is this even allowed?? the above line gives error
java: unexpected type
required: variable
found:    value

Comment: You cannot change the type of a variable after the fact. Even if the syntax would be accepted, you can't modify the type of the variable `a` from `int` to `long` dynamically.

Answer (score 4):

This is not allowed. Casting changes the type of *expressions*, and hence produces an *expression*. The `++` operator increments *variables*, not expressions, so it can't operate on the expression `(long)a`.

For `++(long)a` to make sense, `a` would have the type `long` after it has run, but Java is statically typed. A variable's type can't be changed once it is declared! You can create another variable with type `long`, and assign `a` to it. Then you can increment the new variable without causing overflow.

```
long longA = a;
System.out.println(++longA);
```

Another way is to let the `int` overflow, and treat the overflowed `int` as a `long`:

```
System.out.println(Integer.toUnsignedLong(++a));
```

This will give the illusion that `int`s can suddenly store a wider range of numbers, but actually you are just interpreting the negative `int`s in an alternative way.

Answer (score 1):

`++` does not just increment the value, it also stores the resulting value back - it needs a variable, an expression that can be used in the left side of an assignment - similarly `((long) a = ...` is not valid.

just use `(long)a + 1`

---

Documentation of `++` [JLS 15.15.1. Prefix Increment Operator ++](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.15.1)

> ...  **The result of the unary expression must be a variable ... or a compile-time error occurs.** ...

Casting (`(long)a`) does not result in a variable, it cannot be used.

Answer (score 1):

Let's understand in this way.
`(long)++a` and `(long)a++` will work but in case of `(long)++a` typecasting will happen after increment where bits are already flooded over for int. So, you will not get what you want to achieve. And in your case `++(long)a` this is having invalid argument issue where your code will not compile. But you can do so like this:

```
int a = 2147483647;
long b=(long)a;
System.out.println(++b);
```